# Mongoid batch insert with complicated schema?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I've been going all over the web looking for a solution to my problem. I' m using Mongoid to write a set of data to MongoDB.

I'm trying to do a batch insert with mongoid as follows:

```
class Geonode
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_one :location
  embeds_one :transport

end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :city,        :type => String

  embedded_in :geonode

end

class Transport
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :trainstation
  embedded_in :geonode

end

class Trainstation
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :station, :type => String

  belongs_to :transport

end
```

And it works fine to do it one by one, but if i want to batch a lot of them, what do i do?

i tried.

```
require 'moped'
require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'
require 'mongoid'

require 'skySchema.rb' #schema is the file i defined the classes just before



Mongoid.load!("./mongoid.yml", :development)

include Mongo

batch = []

batch << {:location => Location.new(:city => "London"),
          :transport => Transport.new(:trainstation => 
           [Trainstation.new(:station => "Kings Cross")])}}

and then doing this many many times, after which 

Geonode.collection.insert(batch)
```

but it doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: "does not work" means what?  you get an error? only the first one gets inserted? something else?

Comment: No object is inserted, it just crashes. And i'm wondering if i need to define anything else?

Nothing happens i get the following error: 

.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/mongoid-3.1.4/lib/mongoid/attributes.rb:320:in `method_missing': undefined method `__bson_dump__' for #<Location:0x007ff6b975bb80> (NoMethodError)

Comment: what version of Mongoid is this?  MongoDB drivers didn't always support batch insert syntax so possibly this is a version based on an old Ruby Driver version?

Comment: It's the last version of both mongo and the ruby driver. it also has the latest mongoid.

Comment: Please supply exact version numbers by looking in Gemfile.lock for mongoid, moped, and/or mongo.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I needed to to just Geonode.insert(batch) and format the batch differently. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that for batch insertion, you needed to do :

```
Geonode.insert(batch)
```

And format the batch in a different way. All is cool now.
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: how did you need to format the batch to make it work ?

Comment: @Rafal as far as i remember i did something like

`
    batch = []
    item = { // your stuff here }
    batch << item 
`

and then

`    YourEntity.create(batch)`

or 

`    YourEntity.insert(batch)`

So you add all of the items in an array and then insert that array of things and it will split it into batches depending on your hardware and insert them. My insert rate was about 80 at a time, but this was a while ago and i was running on some pretty bad hardware. 

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, actually I had to call as_document on the embedded class to make it work with batch.
batch << Object.new({:a => 1, :sub_obj => SubObj.new({:b => 2}).as_document}).as_document